# Understanding TMatrix: transpose, invert

Tags: c++, matrix, root-framework

EDIT: TMatrix documentation: https://root.cern.ch/root/html224/TMatrix.html

Say I have two matrices and I want to perform the following simple calculation:

```
TMatrix x(2, 2);
TMatrix M(2, 2);
x.T() * M * x
```

Now this clearly doesn't work, since `x.T()` is destructive. How do obtain a non-destructive transpose function to do this?

Second, say I want to invert a matrix with do the following calculation:

```
TMatrix b(2, 2);
TMatrix A(2, 2);
A(0,0) = A(1,1) = 1e-10;
TMatrix x = A.Invert() * b;
```

This also fails since A is nearly singular. Ideally I would like to use a linear solve to obtain the result `Solve(A, b)` (in other words, solve `Ax = b`). Is there a built in method that does this?

Finally, is there a simple way to multiply a TMatrix by a scalar?

```
TMatrix A(2, 2);
double x = 2.0;
A * x;
```

I am using these cases as simple examples, but I was hoping to generalize this for large problems.

Comment: for multiplying all elements of a TMatrix with a scalar: https://root.cern/doc/v616/classTMatrixT.html#a27e55fc29286c8a90cafa454f67e9247 so `A *= x` and `A * x` just work, EXCEPT `TMatrix` is a typedef for `TMatrixT<float>` so `x` needs to be a `float`, not a `double` for this to work

Comment: for solving the linear equation, did you check the tutorial? https://root.cern/doc/v616/solveLinear_8C.html

Comment: for transposing, did you consider just creating a temporary `decltype(x) tmpX{x}; tmpX.T(); tmpX * M * x;`?